# Wrapping multiple elements into a non-affective element tag in vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

I have this html which makes expandable rows for table element, however its approach works like this:

```
<tbody class="js-table-sections-header">Parent row</tbody>
<tbody>Multiple rows</tbody>
<tbody class="js-table-sections-header">Parent row</tbody>
<tbody>Multiple rows</tbody>
<tbody class="js-table-sections-header">Parent row</tbody>
<tbody>Multiple rows</tbody>
```

It works fine with static values.

However at this point, I want to use Vue and use a `v-for` for my list. But as there are 2 `<tbody>` elements, first, I can't use `v-for` directly, and secondly (as I can't wrap them in a `<div>` to obtain a single parent element) I can't create a component.

My question is: Is there a way to use as a non-affective element tag that I can wrap these multiple `tbody` elements into so I can for loop?

```
<template>
   <non-affective-tag v-for="x in myList">
       <tbody class="js-table-sections-header">One row</tbody>
       <tbody>Multiple rows</tbody>
   </non-affective-tag>
</template>
```

---

Here you can see the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jeaxopwf/2/

And down below, you can see the example:

```js
$('.js-table-sections-header').click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
.js-table-sections-header > tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.js-table-sections-header > tr > td:first-child > i {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.15s ease-out;
}
.js-table-sections-header + tbody {
  display: none;
}
.js-table-sections-header.open > tr {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.js-table-sections-header.open > tr > td:first-child > i {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.js-table-sections-header.open + tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="js-table-sections table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th style="width: 30px;"></th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th style="width: 15%;">Access</th>
           <th class="hidden-xs" style="width: 15%;">Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
                    
    <tbody class="js-table-sections-header open">
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
          </td>
          <td class="font-w600">Sara Holland</td>
          <td>
              <span class="label label-danger">Disabled</span>
          </td>
          <td class="hidden-xs">
              <em class="text-muted">June 7, 2015 12:16</em>
          </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="text-center"></td>
            <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $92,00</td>
            <td>
                <small>Paypal</small>
            </td>
            <td class="hidden-xs">
                <small class="text-muted">June 19, 2015 12:16</small>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="text-center"></td>
             <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $54,00</td>
             <td>
                <small>Paypal</small>
             </td>
             <td class="hidden-xs">
               <small class="text-muted">June 16, 2015 12:16</small>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="text-center"></td>
            <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $84,00</td>
            <td>
                <small>Paypal</small>
            </td>
            <td class="hidden-xs">
                <small class="text-muted">June 26, 2015 12:16</small>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="text-center"></td>
             <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $24,00</td>
             <td>
                 <small>Paypal</small>
             </td>
             <td class="hidden-xs">
                 <small class="text-muted">June 27, 2015 12:16</small>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
     
    <tbody class="js-table-sections-header" v-for="list in myList">
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
          </td>
          <td class="font-w600">Maya</td>
          <td>
              <span class="label label-danger">Disabled</span>
          </td>
          <td class="hidden-xs">
              <em class="text-muted">June 7, 2015 12:16</em>
          </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="text-center"></td>
            <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $82,00</td>
            <td>
                <small>Paypal</small>
            </td>
            <td class="hidden-xs">
                <small class="text-muted">June 19, 2015 12:16</small>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="text-center"></td>
             <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $24,00</td>
             <td>
                <small>Paypal</small>
             </td>
             <td class="hidden-xs">
               <small class="text-muted">June 16, 2015 12:16</small>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="text-center"></td>
            <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $34,00</td>
            <td>
                <small>Paypal</small>
            </td>
            <td class="hidden-xs">
                <small class="text-muted">June 26, 2015 12:16</small>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="text-center"></td>
             <td class="font-w600 text-success">+ $29,00</td>
             <td>
                 <small>Paypal</small>
             </td>
             <td class="hidden-xs">
                 <small class="text-muted">June 27, 2015 12:16</small>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [use the `template` tag with `v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt).

```
<template>
   <template v-for="x in myList">
       <tbody class="js-table-sections-header">One row</tbody>
       <tbody>Multiple rows</tbody>
   </template>
</template>
```

Comment: Wow! Much better than using span or div! Thanks a lot